# Jquery: Toggle between input and text on click

Tags: jquery, html, input

I need to toggle between input and text on click. Something like live edit.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="editInput">Change the value on click</span>
<button>Click me</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var editmode = false;

$('button').on('click',function(){
    if(editmode){    
        $('.editInput').replaceWith(function(){
           return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>';
           editmode = false;
        })
    }else {
        $('.editInput').replaceWith(function(){
           return '<input type="text" value='+this.text+' class='+this.className+'/>';
           editmode = true;
        })    
    }

})
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Instead of replacing them, why don't you put both in the DOM, and just hide one or the other.

Comment: If your app can be HTML5, you can use the contenteditable attribute : http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4c8Xm/).  It's not very elegant, but I think it's a quick, cleaner solution than what you were doing.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

```
<div>
    <input/>
    <span>test</span>
</div>
<button>Update</button>

span {
    display:none;
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
    if($("input").is(":visible")) {  
        $("input").hide();
        $("span").text(
            $("input").val()
        ).show();
        $("button").text("Edit");
    } else {
        $("span").hide();
        $("input").text(
            $("span").val()
        ).show();
        $("button").text("Update");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @joshboley! It works!

And only one thing, it needs to show the span first, and then to show the input on click. I just hid the input in the css, and wrote  the same value in the input.

Comment: Yeah, that should work just fine.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

First, `this.text` should be `this.innerText` or `$(this).text()`.

Second, you need quotes around the `value` attribute in the `<input>` tag, or it won't work with multiple words in the value. It would be even better to use the object form of the jQuery element constructor, so that quotes in the value don't cause a problem, either.

Third, the assignment to `editmode` needs to be outside the `replaceWith` function. It's after the `return` statement, so it's never being executed.

Final result:

var editmode = false;

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    if (editmode) {
        $('.editInput').replaceWith(function () {
            return $("<span>", {
                "class": this.className,
                text: this.value
            });
        });
        editmode = false;
    } else {
        $('.editInput').replaceWith(function () {
            return $("<input>", {
                value: this.innerText,
                    "class": this.className
            });
        });
        editmode = true;
    }

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/93zZ6/6/)